# Is it possible to re-open a file that was selected via the "input file" button programatically

Tags: javascript, fileapi

In my web app the user selects a large zip file via an "input file" button.
The file is then returned as a blob (see the snapshot zipfile1).
The program then reads chunks (individual files) of the zip file one after the other.
A test program reads through all the files in a sequence, and then repeats the sequence multiple times.
This works ok on various OSs (Windows Linux, MacOs, Android) via various browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).
But on iOS sometimes the blob object is lost, and the process returns an error.
In such case I can select the file again to continue the process.

But I would like to do this programatically, without the need for manual intervention.
I still have the filename, but the blob size is 0 (see the snapshot zipfile2).

Is it possible to re-open the file programatically?
Thanks

---

EDIT:

I tried to call

```
let zipFileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(zipFile);
```

to have some kind of a "handle" to the file in memory *without the actual data*.
The idea was that later on, if the file object gets corrupt, I can `fetch(zipFileUrl)` to reopen the file.
Unfortunately, `createObjectURL` creates a memory blob from the *entire* file in memory, which is useless to me because the file is too big...

---

*zipFile1*
[image: zipfile1]

*zipfile2*
[image: zipFile2]

Comment: were you supposed to show us the zipfile1? Could you explain more about the test program and what it does? maybe there is a step in there that is failing

Comment: zipFile1 snapshot is attached. It shows the file object in Javascript.

Comment: The test program shows a button, the user clicks on the button and selects the zip file. The zip file is opened and returned as a blob (see snapshot zipFile1). The program gets the file headers within the zip file, which contains the offsets. It then loops over the headers and opens the individual files (via blob.slice(start, end)) and displays them one after the other. This works in all other OSs and can run many rounds indefinitely. It even works in iOS and sometimes does multiple rounds. So I know that the process is ok. Maybe there is a memory leak but I did not find one so far.

Comment: For now I'm looking for a workaround to use the blob information in snapshot zipfile1, to reopen the file programatically.

Comment: No iOS device to test but that sounds like even the browser has lost the access to that file, so I doubt there is anything we can do at our level about it. Maybe the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) could offer a solution, but I doubt it's accessible in iOS. The only workaround I'd see would be to write that file somewhere your page can access, e.g in memory by copying its content through an ArrayBuffer (which may not be viable for big files), or in IndexedDB. But once again, I can't test to see if that would work.

Comment: `URL.createObjectURL` does not copy the file's data at all, it is just a mere pointer to the file on the disk. That won't help you at all. Once again, try to see if the File System Access API is available and if holding a handle from there prevents the issue, otherwise, try to copy the File to IndexedDB (will be saved in the browser's dedicated storage area, on the user's disk).

Comment: Regarding the comment "URL.createObjectURL does not copy the file's data at all, it is just a mere pointer...."
My hope was that by using URL.createObjectURL I could hold some kind of pointer to the file, 
so I can re-open/re-read portions of the file, after the previous object got corrupted.

Comment: Regarding the IndexDB comment.
Can IndexDB store big file? (~1 GB).
As I understand IndexDB is more suited to smaller amounts of data. I could run a File System Access API example on my iPad, and according to 
https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api
it is supported on iOS. So this gives me some hope.